# insert a list 2xn obtained from a json in python

Tags: python, json, list

Hi I'm trying to access a json to save it in a list to perform a sort of append and create a pdf in ReportLab, I have the following code but I have several problems the first is that I would like to have a list of 2xn to always it has columns and rows be dynamic according to the json.
If anyone can help me be grateful much

```
import json

json_data = []
attributesName = []
testTable = { "attributes":[] }
attributesValue = []
path="prueba2.pdf"
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(path, pagesize=letter)
styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
text = []
with open("prueba.json") as json_file:
document = json.load(json_file)
for item in document:
    for data_item in item['data']:
        attributesName.append([str(data_item['name'])
        attributesValue.append([data_item['value']])
        testTable[attributesName].extend({data_item['name'], data_item['value']})
print attributesName[0]
print testTable[0]
           parts = []
p = Paragraph('''<para align=left fontsize=9>{0}</para>'''.format(text), styleSheet["BodyText"])
parts.append(p)
doc.build(parts)
```

I implemented the following,but it prints the list

```
[[['RFC', 'NOMBRE', 'APELLIDO PATERNO', 'APELLIDO MATERNO', 'FECHA NACIMIENTO', 'CALLE', 'No. EXTERI
OR', 'No. INTERIOR', 'C.P.', 'ENTIDAD', 'MUNICIPIO', 'COLONIA',    'DOCUMENTO']], [['MORR910304FL2', 'R
JOSE', 'MONTIEL', 'ROBLES', '1992-02-04', 'AMOR', '4', '2', '55064', 'EDO DE   MEX', 'ECATEPEC', 'INDUSTRIAL', 'Documento']]]
```

I want some like this

```
[['RFC'], ['22232446']]
[['NOMBRE'], ['22239952']]
[['APELLIDO'], ['22245430']]
```

Comment: What's the issue with the current code?

Comment: Sorry Already i add my issue,i hope help ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you change your code with the next code

```
 with open("prueba.json") as json_file:
    document = json.load(json_file)
    for item in document:
       for data_item in item['data']:
         attributesName.append(str(data_item["name"]))
         attributesValue.append(str(data_item["value"]))
         tabla.append([[attributesName],[attributesValue]])
    print attributesName
    print attributesValue
 for Y in tabla:
    print(Y)
```